# Tensorflow: how to understand the anchors in the tflite model?

Tags: tensorflow, anchor, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I trained a target detection model with mobilenet_v2_ssd, used tflite_convert to convert it to float tflite and unit8 tfilte, and visualized the model with Netron tool.

I found that the final 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess' can extract the input parameter anchors.

It's format is
[
[
4,
4,
15,
15
],
[
4,
4,
22,
44
],
...]

How do you understand the anchors?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Checked from the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/72a31e9e5c06a663a8ee7ff7cc2a41e20557c9e5/research/object_detection/core/box_list.py#L20), they are `ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax`.

You may also find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51742805/ssd-anchors-in-tensorflow-detection-api) useful.